# Unable to push files to my github repository

Tags: git, version-control, github

I've set  up git on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS but whenever I try to push files to my remote repository (`git push -u origin master`), I get the following error-

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

What does this mean? and How can I fix it?

---

I installed Git using the following-

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

My local repository is here-

```
/media/48B9-FD83/foobar
```

it is not in the home directory, it is on a mounted drive  (is that a problem?).

I initialized git in that directory and followed the steps given [here - GitHub's official tutorial](http://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/10).

And when pushing the files, I get those `ssh` and `fatal` errors, mentioned above.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What does `git remote -v` output?

Comment: @Amber `origin git@github.com:username/foobar (fetch)`
`origin git@github.com:username/foobar (push)`

Comment: Have you configured your ssh keys properly? It may be easier for you start out using https. See https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#platform-linux.

Comment: @SahilMuthoo How do I use https?

Comment: You need to generate SSH keys before you can use SSH to communicate with Github. There's a guide to help you through this process: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys After you're done run `ssh -T git@github.com`. If it authenticates and greets you then you're good to go. You should also read the Git SCM book since you're new to Git Revision Control: http://git-scm.com/book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try stuff in this order:

- `ping github.com`. You should not see any timeouts.
- `sudo apt-get install telnet`.
- `telnet github.com 22`. You should see something like this:

---

```
 Trying 204.232.175.90...
 Connected to github.com.
 Escape character is '^]'.
 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1+github9
```

---

- Exit out of telnet by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>.
- Follow steps mentioned in the [Github: Generating ssh keys guide](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#platform-linux).
- Make sure `~/.ssh` and its contents are only readable to you by typing:

  - chmod 0755 `~/.ssh`
  - chmod -R 0600 `~/.ssh/*`
- Next, `ssh -T git@github.com` should say:

---

```
Hi <username>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

---

Report back if you see any error messages while trying any of these commands. Don't forget to post the error message you see in the comment.

Best of luck!

Comment: when I telnet github.com, I get this error - `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out`...

Comment: When I `telnet` github on port 80, it works... but when I try it on port 22, it fails (Connection time out).

Comment: Are you using your company/college/school's internet connection? Have you setup a firewall?

Comment: Alright, that's very strange then. Clearly ssh won't work for you until you can connect to GitHub over port 22. I would suggest following the setting up git over https guide: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#platform-linux. This should work without problem

Comment: Thanks for your help... I was able to push files through HTTP. However still unable to do so using SSH. Are there any (dis)advantages of not using SSH?

Comment: There are  no disadvantages to using https. In fact GitHub prefers and recommends https.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems, always over WIFI, and I think I've found a after lots of searching. My solution is related to the Power Manager. You can check your settings by typing `iwconfig` in ther terminal and you should see something like this:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"MY_NET_NAME"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:00:00:00:00:00   
          Bit Rate=52 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:2  Invalid misc:27   Missed beacon:0
```

The problem is caused by `Power Management:on` (if yours is not on, this solution is not for you).

To disable power management off, type the following in your terminal (replacing `wlan0` with your device):

`sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off`

This fixed my problems. To make the solution permanent, you can add the solution to power manager's startup:

1. Create the script: 
       sudo nano /etc/pm/power.d/wireless
2. Copy paste the following:
       #!/bin/sh
       /sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off
3. Make the file executable
       sudo chmod u+x /etc/pm/power.d/wireless

Hopefully that helps.

This is based on info I found [here](http://www.hitxp.com/articles/software/ubuntu-fix-slow-wireless-internet-connection-speed-upgrading-11-04-natty-narwhal/).